# Python - List sum up every value before from another list

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for a way in python to create a list from another list but always add every value before.

For example i want to create `List2` from `List1`

```py
List1 = [100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0]

List2 = [100, 200, 200, 300, 400, 400, 500, 600, 600]
```

So i always want to add all values before.

I hope it's understandable.

Thank you for every advice.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html?#itertools.accumulate) from the standard library module `itertools`:

```
from itertools import accumulate

list1 = [100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0]
list2 = list(accumulate(list1))
```

gives you

```
[100, 200, 200, 300, 400, 400, 500, 600, 600]
```

as `list2`.

If you don't like that I'd suggest something like:

```
list2 = [list1[0]]
for number in list1[1:]:
    list2.append(list2[-1] + number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop once through the list, adding to each element the one that came before it. This carries down the list, so eventually each element will be a sum of the ones that came before it.

```
list2 = list1.copy()
for i in range(1, len(list1)):
    list2[i] += list2[i-1]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
>>> List1 = [100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0]
>>> list2 = [sum(List1[:i+1]) for i in range(len(List1))]


>>> list2
[100, 200, 200, 300, 400, 400, 500, 600, 600]
```

Comment: This works but it's not efficient: You're doing a lot of summations over and over again. Your approach is `O(n^2)` while you only need `O(n)`. That doesn't matter for the example, but what if the list contains 1 million numbers etc.?

Answer (score 0):

i create this function can help i guess

```
def func(ur_list):
    list2 = []
    list2.append(list[0])
    for i in range(1,len(list)):
        x = list[i]+list2[i-1]
        list2.append(x)    
    return list2
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use built-in function names like `list` as a variable name, as you will lose the reference to those functions.